# A phone troubleshooting program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code should ask the user multiple solutions and find the problem with the users phone. The program should be efficient as possible and have a possible of 10 outcomes. I would like some tips on how I can make the code more efficient and meet the task requirements. This is what the task states:

> Analyse the requirements for this system and design, develop, test and evaluate a program to
>   interrogate the user about the nature of the device and the problem, leading to a solution or advice to
>   call the supplier. You will need to create a suitable troubleshooting tree for a mobile device. This should
>   be a demonstration version of the system with at least 10 possible outcomes, but need not include an
>   exhaustive list of potential problems or outcomes.

```
import webbrowser
import random
print("Welcome to a phone troubleshooting program")
sol1 = ("Keep holding the power on button until the screen is on. If it doesn't turn on, contact your phone provider to get a replacement.")
sol2 = ("Charge your phone fully and switch it on.")
sol3 = ("Delete some apps, you need a minimum of at least 5 GB of free  memory to run the phone correcly.You are probably out of memory.")
sol4 = ("Reset your phone.")
sol5 = ("You need a screen replacement. Either got to a shop or ask your insurance company covers the phone")
sol5 = ("You need to get your buttons replaced!")
sol6 = ("Get a screen replacement or contact your phone provider to get a  phone replacement.")
sol7 = ("You dont need to do anything. Your phone doesnt have any problems.")
sol8 = ("Please update your phone software.")
sol9 = ("The best advice that I would suggest is to either contact apple for support or visit a shop to get it fixed")
sol10 = ("Take the phone and put it in a bag of rice for  24-36 hours to let the rice absorb the water.")
while True:
    def apple():
         prob_1 = None
         while prob_1 not in ('software','hardware'):
            prob_1 = input("Is your problem hardware or software").lower()

            if prob_1 == 'software':
                prob_2 = None
                while prob_2 not in ('yes','no'):
                    prob_2 = input("Does your iphone still turn on : yes or no").lower()

                if prob_2 == 'yes':
                    prob_3 = None
                    while prob_3 not in ('yes','no'):
                        prob_3 = input("Has your phone slowed down during usage?").lower()

                elif prob_2 == 'no':
                        print("Keep holding the power on button until the screen is on. If it doesn't turn on, contact your phone provider to get a replacement.")
                        rnd = (int(random.randrange(50)) + 1)
                        print("If that does not work you should contact the apple. With the case number", str(rnd))

                if prob_3 == 'yes':
                            print("Delete some apps, you need a minimum of at least 5 GB of free  memory to run the phone correcly.You are probably out of memory.")

                elif prob_3 == 'no':
                    prob_4 = ("Is there a reacurrance of a bug in the phone").lower()
                    if prob_4 == 'yes':
                        print("install a antivirus or reinstall/udate the app")
                        WebCho = input("Would you like to visit the apple site to check if you still have a warranty left for your phone: yes / no").lower()
                        if WebCho == 'yes':
                                     webbrowser.open("http://www.apple.com/uk/support/")
                        elif WebCho == 'no':
                                     print("Hopefully you get the phone fixed. Contact us for more queries")
                    elif prob_4 == 'no':
                        print(sol7) 

            elif prob_1 == 'hardware':
                    prob = None
                    while prob not in ('yes','no'):
                        prob = input("Has your phone been in contact with water in the last 48 hours").lower()
                    if prob == 'yes':
                        prob2 = None
                        while prob2 not in ('yes','no'):
                            prob2 = input("Does your iphone still turn on").lower()

                            if prob2 == 'no':
                                print(sol10)
                                print("if that doesnt work then try", sol9)
                            elif prob2 == 'yes':
                                prob6 = input("Has the water entered the internal screen")
                                if prob6 == 'yes':
                                    print("You should contact apple. They will deal with your case. If the phone still has the 1 year warranty then it will be cost free.\n If not then you will have to pay")
                                    print("If it not fixable then you should look for a replacent")
                                    break
                                elif prob6 == 'no':
                                    print(sol7)
                    elif prob =='no':
                            prob_3 = input("Is your phone screen cracked or not: yes / no").lower()
                            if prob_3 == 'yes':
                                    print("The best advice that I would suggest is to either contact apple for support or visit a shop to get the screen fix")
                                    WebCho = input("Would you like to visit the apple site to check if you still have a warranty left for your phone: yes / no").lower()
                                    if WebCho == 'yes':
                                                 webbrowser.open("http://www.apple.com/uk/support/")
                                    elif WebCho == 'no':
                                                 print("Hopefully you get the phone fixed.  Contact us for more queries")
                            elif prob_3 == 'no':
                                    prob4 = input("Are your headphone port or charing port not working").lower()
                                    if prob4 == 'yes':
                                        prob5 = None
                                        while prob5 not in ('earphone port','earphone','headphone','headphone port','charging','charging port'):
                                            prob5 = input("Which port is not working : earphone/headphone port or charing port").lower()
                                        if prob5 == 'earphone port':
                                                print("The best advice that I would suggest is to either contact apple for support or visit a shop to get it fixed")
                                        elif prob5 ==  'charging port':
                                                print("You should contact us for more detail and we will look futher into the problem and hopefully we can fix it ASAP")
                                                print("Your case number is", rnd,"Use this number when contacting our repair service.")


    def android():
       prob_1 = None
       while prob_1 not in ('software','hardware'):
            prob_1 = input("Is your problem hardware or software").lower()

            if prob_1 == 'software':
                prob_2 = None
                while prob_2 not in ('yes','no'):
                    prob_2 = input("Does your iphone still turn on : yes or no").lower()

                if prob_2 == 'yes':
                    prob_3 = None
                    while prob_3 not in ('yes','no'):
                        prob_3 = input("Has your phone slowed down during usage?").lower()
                if prob_3 == 'yes':
                            print("Delete some apps, you need a minimum of at least 5 GB of free  memory to run the phone correcly.You are probably out of memory.")
                elif prob_2 == 'no':
                        print("Keep holding the power on button until the screen is on. If it doesn't turn on, contact your phone provider to get a replacement.")
                        rnd = (int(random.randrange(50)) + 1)
                        print("If that does not work you should contact the apple. With the case number", str(rnd))

                elif prob_3 == 'no':
                    prob_4 = ("Is there a virus in the phone").lower()
                    if prob_4 == 'yes':
                        print("install a antivirus or stuuf")
                        WebCho = input("Would you like to visit the apple site to check if you still have a warranty left for your phone: yes / no").lower()
                        if WebCho == 'yes':
                                     webbrowser.open("http://www.apple.com/uk/support/")
                        elif WebCho == 'no':
                                     print("Hopefully you get the phone fixed. Contact us for more queries")
                    elif prob_4 == 'no':
                        print(sol7) 

            elif prob_1 == 'hardware':
                    prob = None
                    while prob not in ('yes','no'):
                        prob = input("Has your phone been in contact with water in the last 48 hours").lower()
                    if prob == 'yes':
                        prob2 = None
                        while prob2 not in ('yes','no'):
                            prob2 = input("Does your iphone still turn on").lower()

                            if prob2 == 'no':
                                print(sol10)
                                print("if that doesnt work then try", sol9)
                            elif prob2 == 'yes':
                                prob6 = input("Has the water entered the internal screen")
                                if prob6 == 'yes':
                                    print("You should contact apple. They will deal with your case. If the phone still has the 1 year warranty then it will be cost free.\n If not then you will have to pay")
                                    print("If it not fixable then you should look for a replacent")
                                    break
                                elif prob6 == 'no':
                                    print(sol7)
                    elif prob =='no':
                            prob_3 = input("Is your phone screen cracked or not: yes / no").lower()
                            if prob_3 == 'yes':
                                    print("The best advice that I would suggest is to either contact apple for support or visit a shop to get the screen fix")
                                    WebCho = input("Would you like to visit the apple site to check if you still have a warranty left for your phone: yes / no").lower()
                                    if WebCho == 'yes':
                                                 webbrowser.open("http://www.apple.com/uk/support/")
                                    elif WebCho == 'no':
                                                 print("Hopefully you get the phone fixed.  Contact us for more queries")
                            elif prob_3 == 'no':
                                    prob4 = input("Are your headphone port or charing port not working").lower()
                                    if prob4 == 'yes':
                                        prob5 = None
                                        while prob5 not in ('earphone port','earphone','headphone','headphone port','charging','charging port'):
                                            prob5 = input("Which port is not working : earphone/headphone port or charing port").lower()
                                        if prob5 == 'earphone port':
                                                print("The best advice that I would suggest is to either contact apple for support or visit a shop to get it fixed")
                                        elif prob5 ==  'charging port':
                                                print("You should contact us for more detail and we will look futher into the problem and hopefully we can fix it ASAP")
                                                print("Your case number is", rnd,"Use this number when contacting our repair service.")



    phone_Ty = input("What type of phone do you have : apple / android").lower()
    if phone_Ty == 'apple':
        apple()
        WebCho = input("Would you like to visit the apple site to check if you still have any queries: yes / no").lower()
        if WebCho == 'yes':
                     webbrowser.open("http://www.apple.com/uk/support/")
        elif WebCho == 'no':
                     print("Hopefully you get the phone fixed.  Contact us for more queries")



    elif phone_Ty == 'android':
        android()
        WebCho = input("Would you like to visit the apple site to check if you still have a warranty left for your phone: yes / no").lower()
        if WebCho == 'yes':
                     webbrowser.open("http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/")
        elif WebCho == 'no':
                     print("Hopefully you get the phone fixed.  Contact us for more queries")
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Data-structure based programming

In your current code you are building a tree of the possible answers with nested `if`, `elif` and `while`, reaching a nesting depth of 9, rendering it very hard to guess where the an additional troubleshooting recommendation should be added.

I suggest listing the solution to each case in a dictionary, and index it with the given user input, you can see an example down here:

```
SOLUTIONS = { {"android" : True, "software" : True, "turns_on" : False} : "Keep holding the power on button until the screen is on", 
              ... }


case = { "android"  : yes_no("Is it android?"),
         "software" : yes_no("Is it software"),
         "turns_on" : yes_no("Does it turn on?")     }

print(SOLUTIONS[case])
```

Handling cases for which you have no suggestion may be done with `try`, `except`, instead in your code you repeat the *i don't know* code many times:

```
try:
    print(SOLUTIONS[case])
except KeyError:
    print("I do not know the solution to this case, better ask official support")
```